# Having trouble with web scraping

Tags: python, selenium

So I have no idea what I'm doing with web scraping, so naturally I looked up tutorials, and yet none of them seem to work ever. Can someone help with my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_chromedriver_win32.zip\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://toscrape.com/')
results = []
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for element in soup.findAll(attrs='title'):
    name = element.find('title')
    results.append(name.text)
for x in results:
    print(x)
```

Comment: your executable_path >> you should not call a .exe in a zip file...

Comment: I don't really use BeautifulSoup but it looks like you forgot to import bs4? `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: What was the output you needed just the title text?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to print the soup's title text.

```
driver.get('http://toscrape.com/')
results = []
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
print(soup.title.text)
```

Import

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Outputs

**Scraping Sandbox**